# Resizing window always trigger a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap sidebar that can be toggled into a narrow icon bar, and now I am required to show the sidebar when screen height is greater than 768, and to a narrow side bar when height is lower than 768. But my script appears to be triggering a click event when lower than 768, therefore if I resize the screen multiple times, and when height reaches lower than 768, it continuously toggles the sidebar multiple times. If the height reaches greater than 768, the toggling stops.

My code is:

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        $("span", this).toggleClass("fa fa-lock fa fa-unlock");
    });
$("#menu-toggle-2").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled-2");
        $("span", this).toggleClass("fa fa-lock fa fa-unlock");
    });

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $window = $(window);

        // Function to handle changes to style classes based on window width
        function checkWidth() {
          if ($window.height() <= 768) {
              $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled-2");

          }
          else if ($window.height() > 768) {
              $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
          }
      }

    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
        $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: This can all be done with css media queries

Comment: Given the code you've shared, there's no way a resize is triggering a click.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the click event is triggering? (Try making a log inside the click function(s) to confirm using `console.log`)

Based on the code you posted it looks like `resize` may be firing multiple times as you resize the window.

Try using the following:

```
$(window).resize($.throttle(checkWidth, 300));
```

Throttle returns a new function that executes no more than once every 300ms (or whatever delay you decide to set)

Note: This uses jQuery debounce/throttle plugin

https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-debounce/